# How to get a list object to append values when using futures in Python?

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

```
from concurrent import futures

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mylist = []

    def test(self, i):
        self.mylist.append(i)

myclass = MyClass()

print(myclass.mylist)

ilist = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in ilist:
    myclass.test(i)

print(myclass.mylist)

myclass.mylist = []
with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
    for null in pool.map(myclass.test, ilist):
        pass

print(myclass.mylist)
```

Output:

```
[]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[]
```

Why does appending values in `def test` to `self.mylist` work in conventional loop but not when using futures?  How to allow append in function while using futures?

Comment: because you are using *multiple processes* which *do not share state*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets tweak the program a bit so that the function executed by the pool returns the list and also lets print the address of the `MyClass` object.

```py
from concurrent import futures

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mylist = []

    def test(self, i):
        print(hex(id(self)), self.mylist, i)
        self.mylist.append(i)
        return self.mylist

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myclass = MyClass()
    ilist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    myclass.mylist = []
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        for null in pool.map(myclass.test, ilist):
            print(f'Output of process: {null}')    
    print(f'addr: {hex(id(myclass))} , {myclass.mylist}')
```

gives the output

```
Output of process: [1]
Output of process: [2]
Output of process: [3]
Output of process: [4]
0x1b88e358860 [] 1
0x20bffa28908 [] 3
0x259844b87f0 [] 2
0x1d7546d8898 [] 4
addr: 0x20e5ebc5400 , []
```

As you could see each process is handling a different copy of the `MyClass` object.

Lets now replace the `ProcessPoolExecutor` with `ThreadPoolExecutor`. 
Now the result looks like this:

```
0x1a323eb5438 [] 1
0x1a323eb5438 [1] 2
0x1a323eb5438 [1, 2] 3
0x1a323eb5438 [1, 2, 3] 4
Output of process: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Output of process: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Output of process: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Output of process: [1, 2, 3, 4]
addr: 0x1a323eb5438 , [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now each thread is dealing with the same object.

In short, processes have their own memory and is not shared across the processes.